# The difference between the fair market value of the donated item and the amount of an advantage, if any, is the qualifying amount of a gift

Tags: canada, tax-law, gift

What does "the amount of an advantage" refer to in "[the difference between the fair market value of the donated item and the amount of an advantage, if any, is the qualifying amount of a gift](https://filingtaxes.ca/in-canada-how-much-money-can-you-gift-a-friend-or-family-member-without-them-being-taxed-for-it/)"? Could someone please give an example? Thank you!

Comment: Note that the clause in the link relates to gifts made to such as a registered charity or municipality. I suppose, that if your membership subscription to a charitable society is $100 and you donate something of market value $150 to pay for it, the qualifying amount on which you will get a tax credit is $50.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what is being discussed is a situation like a bargain sale or a below market rental arrangement.

I think what makes the phrase "The difference between the fair market value of the donated item and the amount of an advantage, if any, is the qualifying amount of a gift" is that the sentence should really clarify that they are talking about the advantage to the donor.

Suppose that you grandfather allows you to buy a yacht, which he purchased the previous day in an arms-length transaction with a third-party which is presumptively fair market value at $10,000,000 for $100,000. The advantage to your grandfather is $100,000, and the fair market value of the gift is $9,900,000.

A more common situation for this to come up would be a charity auction, where you bid far more than fair market value on an item, in benefit the charity. You might bid $1,000 for a one night stay at a local motel that usually charges $100 for that. What you give is $1,000 cash less the advantage of $100 that you receive.